# Unable to get a token for an app user Box API

Tags: api, access-token, box-api, box

I created an application in Box.com and authorized it in my Box Business account with "Only App Users of this App" permission. Using the api and App credentials I created an App user. Now, when I tried to use that user id to get a token, I get an error `Cannot obtain user token based on the enterprise configuration for your app`.

What is required to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

[This error was caused by a bug](https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/Cannot-obtain-user-token-based-on-the-enterprise-configuration/m-p/18639#U18639) in the Box API. The issue should now be resolved.